# How to set background image to outermost div depending child div presence?

Tags: html, css

The html is like:-

```
<div class="mainWrapper">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Css:-

```
.mainWrapper
{
background-color: #FFF;
overflow: auto;
min-height: 500px;
} 
#left
{
float: left;
padding: 0;
width: 182px;
}   
#right
{
float: left;
padding: 20px;
width: 500px;
}   
.twoColumns
{
background-color: #FFF;
overflow: auto;
min-height: 500px;
border: 0px solid black;
overflow: auto;
background-image: url(/image.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: top left;
}
```

The css class "twoColumns" will be added to "mainWrapper" class if div with **id=left** is present. The background image(of color #363636) will be given to outermost div. If css class(twoColumns) is added in document ready(depending #left presence), it is taking time to bring the image from server. How to add the background image to outermost div depending upon the child div presence? Any idea/suggestion to solve this problem is applauded.

Comment: Can't be done with pure CSS as it can't go "up" the dom. You'll have to use Javascript/jquery

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest placing the image into the wrapper from the start, then removing it under your respective conditions.  All this can be easily achieved with a little css change and javascript:

CSS:

```
.mainWrapper
{
background-color: #FFF;
overflow: auto;
min-height: 500px;
    background-image: url(http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/abstract-background.jpg);
} 
#left
{
float: left;
padding: 0;
width: 182px;
}   
#right
{
float: left;
padding: 20px;
width: 500px;
}   
.twoColumns
{
background-color: #FFF;
overflow: auto;
min-height: 500px;
border: 0px solid black;
overflow: auto;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: top left;
}​
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".mainWrapper #left").length == 0){
        $(".mainWrapper").css({'background-image':'none'});
    }

});​
```

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/fcVpJ/)